# Removing items of an array from stage in as3- one each time

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to remove movieclips of an array from the stage. I want to remove one item of the circles array every time there is a click in an item from the square array. I wrote this code but something is missing and i can not figure it out because all the items of the circles array disappear from stage with the first click. Can you please help me.

```
var circles:Array = [circle1, circle2, circle3, circle4,circle5, circle6];
var counter:int = 0; 

var square:Array = new Array(square1,square2,square3,square4,square5,square6,square7,square8,square9,square10,square11,square12,square13,square14,square15,square16,square17,square18,square19,square20,square21);

for(var i:int = 0; i < square.length; i++)
{
    square[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickTomove);

    function clickTomove(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        trace("square");
        var len:int=circles.length;
        for(var o:int=0; o<circles.length; o++)
        this.removeChild(circles[o]); 
        circles.splice(o,1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your click handler loops through the circles and removes them all, so what you're describing is expected.
- You shouldn't put function declarations inside a loop.

It looks like you're trying to do something like this:

```
for each (var square:MovieClip in squares) {
    square.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickTomove);
}

function clickTomove(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if (circles.length > 0) {
        var circle:MovieClip = circles.pop();
        removeChild(circle);
    }
}
```

[`pop()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#pop()) removes and returns the last item from the circles array.